# Lodash / javascript : Compare two collections and return the differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have two arrays of objects:

Elements of my tables are not primitive value, but complex objects.

```
array1 = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4]
array2 = [obj5,obj5,obj6,obj7]
```

I would like to compare two arrays and see if the elements of array2 are already present in array1 then create a new array of the difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yep, `_.difference`

Comment: so this was marked duplicate by 6 people? do those 6 people even know the difference between an array of primitives and an array of complex objects?

Comment: I think lodash _.differenceBy(https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceBy) could help.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
var presents = _.intersectionWith(array1, array2, _.isEqual);
var dif = _.differenceWith(array1, array2, _.isEqual);
```

**_.differenceWith is only available since 4.0.0 lodash version**

Comment: _.differenceWith is only available since 4.0.0 lodash version

Comment: did you see he ask about :::: arrays of objects
array1 = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4]
array2 = [obj5,obj5,obj6,obj7]

Answer (score 29):

**ES6** This will be enough:

```
array2.filter(e => !array1.includes(e));
```

without **includes**

```
array2.filter(e=> array1.indexOf(e) < 0);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cHOFhKBAgtmjI28gtxQo) for you

Comment: can't use your solution since i'am using angular 2 with typescript, includes return an error

Comment: this is NOT enough. you are using primitive values in the plunkr, OP is not

Answer (score 8):

[_.difference](https://lodash.com/docs/#difference) gives you only the elements that are in the 1st array but not in the second one, nothing about the elements on the array 2 that are not in the array 1.

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes this is what i'am trying to achieve, but when i use _difference in the case that my two array are idantical  i have array1 as output ! is it normal ?

Comment: no... should send you [] (I've tested it now on chrome console in lodash docs...). are you using nodejs or a web browser?

Comment: yeah finally it works fine, it was an error made by me . thx for your help