# Comparison of array of objects in the same collection with similar properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to compare each object in the array.

Let's say below is my array:

```
var objects = [{
        'x': 1,
        'y': 2
    }, {
        'x': 2,
        'y': 1
    },{
        'x': 3,
        'y': 1
    },{
        'x': 4,
        'y': 1
    }];
```

Given two items, say `item1` and `item2`, I need to check the condition `item1.x == item2.y` and `item1.y == item2.x` through the array.

Is there a clean/efficient way to do in **Lodash**?

Comment: You want to compare and then? You want to convert that array into an array of booleans?

Comment: if condition matches , needs to push new value (say 'maches' : true) for both the objects

Comment: What is the difference between `x==y and y == x`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lodash / javascript : Compare two collections and return the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656124/lodash-javascript-compare-two-collections-and-return-the-differences)

Comment: I think by `x==y and y == x` he means `item1.x == item2.y  and item1.y == item2.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var objects = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 1},
    {'x': 3, 'y': 1},
    {'x': 4, 'y': 1}
];
    
var comparedLodash = _.map(objects, function (item) {
  return !!_.find(objects, {x: item.y, y: item.x}); 
});
console.log(comparedLodash);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Complexity of this is ***O(n^2)***.

<sub>Note: You could make it *O(nlogn)* if you sorted the array before starting the comparison, but this would add significant noise to the code.</sub>

## Breakdown:

The [**`_.map(somearray, somefunction)` function**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map) executes the `somefunction` into every element of `somearray`. We will use it to convert every item of the `objects` array into a boolean. Roughly it is like:

```
var comparedLodash = _.map(objects, functionThatWillConvertAnItemIntoABoolean);
```

Now, each `item1` should be converted `true` if there's `anotherItem` with `item1.x == anotherItem.y` and `item1.y == anotherItem.x`. To find if this another item exists, we use [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#find).

[**`_.find(somearray, someobject)`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#find) tries to if the `someobject` exists in the `somearray`. That is why we do, above, something like:

```
function (item) {
  var anotherItem = {x: item.y, y: item.x}
  return _.find(objects, anotherItem); 
}
```

Lastly, `_.find` returns the object, if found, and `undefined` if not found. We use `!!` to convert that to boolean (`!!undefined` becomes `false` and `!!someobject` becomes `true`).

Comment: can you please explain me shortly

Comment: Added explanation. Check the answer, please

Comment: Great :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = _.map(objects, function(item) {
    if (item.x == item.y) return item;
});

var filteredNewArray = _.without(newArray, undefined)

console.log(filteredNewArray)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Fraser, remember next time sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map.
This may help,

```
objects.map((value, index) => {
    return value.x == value.y
})
```